# 2.8 of 4.0 GB RAM usable on a Windows 7 Notebook

Tags: windows-7, intel-gma

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does Windows only show about 3.5GB of my 4GB+ of RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/27086/why-does-windows-only-show-about-3-5gb-of-my-4gb-of-ram)  
>   [Why can't Windows 7 x64 use all installed memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/20299/why-cant-windows-7-x64-use-all-installed-memory)

On Acer 1830t notebook with 4GB RAM (Intel HM55 Express + Intel GMA HD) and custom Windows 7 install Intel® HD Graphics utility reports

```
Physical Memory:        2869 MB
Minimum Graphics Memory:    128 MB
Maximum Graphics Memory:    1306 MB
```

There's no BIOS setting to disable shared video memory.
How do I bring RAM back to 4GB?

Comment: Was the custom Win7 install a 32bit version by chance?

Comment: It can also be that the Graphics is using up the missing main memory as shared video memory. Not much you can do if this is the case, unless the driver allows you to trim it back, it would be found in Graphics properties if it exists.

Comment: 1 vote for being closed prematurely. At least let the OP post if it is 32 or 64bit. Specs say it is 64bit...http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/2010/Acer/Aspire/Aspire1830T/Aspire1830Tsp2.shtml

Comment: @Moab still a dupe http://superuser.com/questions/20299/why-cant-windows-7-x64-use-all-installed-memory

Comment: @Moab "pity voting" is not encouraged, though you are free to vote as you see fit. As @Sathya points out, the question has still been asked before regardless.

Comment: Not the same question, disagree.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running a 32 bit version of Windows. This is a limitation of the 32 bit systems (and certain 64 bit systems, depending on the motherboards chipset) that limits how much RAM is available to the operating system. Here is a good discussion of the issue:

[The 3GB-not-4GB RAM problem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hiltonl/the-3gb-not-4gb-ram-problem)